# Mongo - How to update a property of a document using a nested value of the same document

Tags: mongodb, update

I want to update a document using a nested value from that same document.  So if I have an document that looks like this:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId("60b002d490b01b63eee5d4b7"),
  title: 'foo',
  meta: {
    createdTime: ISODate("2011-07-06T17:53:41.439Z"),
    updatedTime: ISODate("2021-07-06T17:53:41.432Z")
  }
}
```

I want to run a database operation that will copy the `meta.updatedTime` to another field (that we can call `newProperty`) on the document so that the end result would be this:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId("60b002d490b01b63eee5d4b7"),
  title: 'foo',
  meta: {
    createdTime: ISODate("2011-07-06T17:53:41.439Z"),
    updatedTime: ISODate("2021-07-06T17:53:41.432Z")
  },
  newProperty: ISODate("2021-07-06T17:53:41.432Z")
}
```

I know that I can do a `find` to get the document and then a separate `update`, but I was hoping to be able to do it all in one operation.  This way if I'm running this operation on 50,000 or 100,000 records, I get the sense that a simple db operation would be faster than looping through the records and performing an operation on each one using javascript.  But that might be negligible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {}, 
    [ 
       { $addFields: { newProperty: "$meta.updatedTime" } } 
    ]
)
```

Comment: When I do this, the string is literally added to the new property.  Instead of `newProperty: ISODate("2021-07-06T17:53:41.432Z")`, I see `newProperty: "$meta.updatedTime"`

Comment: @JoshReep if you are using MongoDB v4.2 or higher, the above update operation should work fine; see [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: In the above code `$addField`  aggregation stage name (produces syntax error) should be `$addFields`.

Answer (score 0):

If you get error `Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addField'` when using `$addField`, give the below statement a shot.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {},
    [
       { $set: { newProperty: "$meta.createdTime" } }
    ]
)
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `$addFields` (`$addField` produces a syntax error).